# Diamond made of numbers in C++ using only recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I currently have code that displays a number triangle:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void RowNumbers(int n, int max) {
    if (n < max) {
        cout << n << ' ';
        RowNumbers(n + 1, max);
    }
    cout << n << ' ';
}

void PrintRhombus(int n, int space = 0) {
    if (n > 1) {
        PrintRhombus(n - 1, space + 2);
    }
    cout << string(space, ' ');
    RowNumbers(1, n);
    cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number [1-9]: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    if (a > 0 && a < 10) {
        PrintRhombus(a, 0);
    }
    else
        cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
}
```

The output is displayed here if the input is two.

```
  1
1 2 1
```

This is only half of what I want. I want to make a full diamond, so I would want a "1" as the third line of this output. The RowNumbers function generates each line, and the PrintRhombus function is responsible for creating the number triangle. I only want to use recursions to create the bottom half of the triangle. So should I create another recursion function that creates the bottom half of the diamond? Or should I build upon the PrintRhombus function, and start something else when the value reaches one.

So once again my goal is to create a number diamond, so if you input 3, then the output is:

```
    1
  1 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
  1 2 1
    1
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this needs to be done with recursion? A much simpler, more readable program could be created if you lifted this restriction.

Comment: I know there is a way to do this without recursions, but this is for a homework assignment, and I am restricted with only using recursions...

Comment: Nitpick: please [don't space/format your code like that](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26310838/1) (edited).  It's true that formatting has a lot of subjectivity involved...whether to put the brace on the next line/etc.  But putting lots of stray lines like that is not something you see in practice...for good reason.  The personal-choice aspect of it does wind up causing actual issues in Q&A here, as it makes unnecessary scroll bars on code excerpts and you can't see everything on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

First, write `PrintRhombus` in the form of a single loop:

```
void PrintRhombus(int n) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 2 * n; i++){
        int numbers_in_line = i < n ? i : 2 * n - i;
        int space = (n - numbers_in_line) * 2;
        cout << string( space, ' ' );
        RowNumbers( 1, numbers_in_line );
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Test your loop and make sure you got it right. It's usually much easier to reason about a loop than a recursive function.

Now transform the loop into a tail-recursive function. This transformation is trivial to perform:

```
void PrintRhombus(int n, int i = 1){
                         // ^ loop variable --> extra parameter 
    if(i == 2 * n) return;  // <- terminating condition --> return

    // loop body remains unchanged
    int numbers_in_line = i < n ? i : 2 * n - i;
    int space = (n - numbers_in_line) * 2;
    cout << string( space, ' ' );
    RowNumbers( 1, numbers_in_line );
    cout << endl;

    // Now do recursive call with incremented loop variable
    PrintRhombus(n, i+1);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f594cd981e1d44a1).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you only iterate to the top of the rhombus, then print out the top half.  I could not find a solution that used only one function, but here are two functions, one for the top and one for the bottom, that work:

```
void PrintRhombusTop(int n, int space = 0)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        PrintRhombusTop(n - 1, space + 2);
    }
    cout << string(space, ' ');
    RowNumbers(1, n);
    cout << "\n";
}

void PrintRhombusBottom(int n, int space)
{
    if (n >= 1)
    {
        cout << string(space, ' ');
        RowNumbers(1, n);
        cout << "\n";
        PrintRhombusBottom(n - 1, space + 2);
    }
}
```

Call them in `main` like this:

```
if (a > 0 && a < 10)
{
    PrintRhombusTop(a, 0);
    PrintRhombusBottom(a - 1, 2);
}
```

You need to pass `(a - 1, 2)` to `PrintRhombusBottom` so you don't print the middle row twice and so the row after the middle row is indented correctly.

Comment: Sorry about posting the incomplete answer at first, I accidentally hit `Tab` and `Enter` in rapid succession.

Comment: Hold on, it has a bug when you enter `1`.

Comment: OK, fixed and tested.

Answer (score 0):

to follow the same logic as `RowNumber`, you probably want something like that:

```
void PrintRhombus(int min, int max)
{
    if (min < max)
    {
        RowNumber(1, min);
        PrintRhombus(min+1, max);
        RowNumber(1, min);
    }
    else
        RowNumber(1, max);
}
```

Just add the necessary spaces

Answer (score 0):

Another one for fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void row(int n, int m) {
  std::cout << n << " ";
  if (n < m) {
    row(n + 1, m);
    std::cout << n << " "; } }

void line(int n, int r, int m) {
  std::cout << std::string(2 * (m - n), ' ');
  row(1, r);
  std::cout << "\n"; }

void diamond(int n, int r, int m) {
  line(n, r, m);
  if (r < m) {
    diamond(n + 1, r + 1, m);
    line(n, r, m); } }

int main(int, char* []) {
  std::cout << "Number? ";
  int n = 0;
  std::cin >> n;
  diamond(1, 1, n);
  return 0; }
```